# unexpected new line in build.xml

Tags: java, xml, build

I recently made a build.xml to run my java class and a test class. However when I ran it in unix by `./build.xml`

It gave me a error:

```
./build.xml: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./build.xml: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0"?>'
```

This is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default='test'>
<target name='test' depends='compile'>
<junit>
<formatter type='plain'/>
<test name='gIntTest'/>
<classpath>
<pathelement path="."/>
</classpath>
</junit>
<java classname="gIntTest" classpath="." fork="true" />
</target>
<target name="compile">
<javac srcdir="." includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to indent your files so they are human readable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*build.xml* is run by [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), not `./build.xml`, if you run it like `./build.xml`, you are running as `shellscript`.

build.xml should execute like:

- `ant -f build.xml`
- `ant`

Comment: Oh, got it. By the way, is there anything wrong in my build file?